# Mesibo API on Microsoft Edge

Tags: mesibo

My query is related to Mesibo Javascript SDK. I have integrated Mesibo into my website and was testing it on all browsers but the chat popup does't seem to be working specifically on Microsoft edge. Here is the video of the same: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yyzJn-LDRYAjLQb4DZLOg4i5ApCR9i4W/view?usp=sharing

Can somone please tell me if Mesibo SDK is usually not compatible with Microsoft Edge browser and if not, how can the problem on the video be fixed.

Apart from that, can you also please tell me if the Javascript SDK for Mesibo provides an API to tell the user if he has a new message in a chat (like whatsapp displays "1" on a chat if there is a new message from that person)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

mesibo API does not provide any UI, what you are using is the sample code which you can modify to suit your needs.

Read tutorials here, you need to set listener to get new message notification. https://mesibo.com/documentation/tutorials/first-app/js/

Comment: I have already set the listeners and the chat is working perfectly fine on other browsers apart from edge. I need to know if this is due to compatability issues of Mesibo SDK with the browser.

Comment: Do you see any error logs in the console? chat popup is not SDK.